# How to change citation style in amsrefs?

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs

I want to use the alphabetic style of citation in amsrefs, e.g. I want [Kr03] instead of just [1].  The documentation says that there is an option to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to invoke this option.

Sorry for the dumb question.  I am appropriately embarrassed already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `alphabetic` package option:

```
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs}
```